# Spring Data [ persist object in Hbase]

Tags: spring, orm, hbase, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When browsing in the Spring site, I had a doubt. it is possible to use the  [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/)  for OMR, ie make the persistence of Java objects in Hbase.

Works like Kundera and DataNucleus?

Answer (score 2):

The [Spring for Hadoop](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#springandhadoop-hbase) project provides integration of Hadoop (including HBase) with a Spring application.  It provides a `Template` class for interacting with Hadoop components.  Many other Spring modules provide similar `Template` classes (`JdbcTemplate`, `LdapTemplate`, etc.).

The [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) modules on the other hand provide access to the underlying data stores through a `Repository` pattern.  Currently there is no known native or third-party integration of the Spring Data project with the Spring for Hadoop project (see the Spring Data project's home page for the list of supported backends).

However, it is possible to wrap the functionality provided by the Spring for Hadoop project (basically the `Template`) inside a `Repository` implementation.  For example, see the source code for the [Spring Data Solr](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr) project that provides a [Template](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/core/SolrTemplate.java) and a [Repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/support/SimpleSolrRepository.java) that uses the `Template`.  Something similar can be built out from the Spring for Hadoop project for HBase.